# Inserting a birthdate with Date in NoSql

Tags: mongodb, date, nosql, runtime-error

I am trying to insert a birthday with Date type in NoSQL like this

```
db.employees.insertOne({
  "Name": "Alison Davison",
  birthday:  Date("Apr 05, 1975"),
  "Address": "874 W. Oak Place",
  "City": "Gary",
  "State": "Indiana",
  Position:{Name: "Customer Support", Remote: true, Full Time: true}
});
```

And is throwing this error

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :
@(shell):7:63
```

Comment: MongoDB, I tried this now 
db.employees.insertOne(
    {"Name": "Alison Davison",
        birthday:  Date("Apr 05, 1975"),
        "Address": "874 W. Oak Place",
        "City": "Gary",
        "State": "Indiana",
        Position:{Name: "Customer Support", Remote: true, FullTime: true}
     } );

Comment: It runed but is stamping my time and not showing the the date that I assigned

Comment: db.employees.find({}).pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f38ac70c80fe1b3848d271e"),
        "Name" : "Alison Davison",
        "birthday" : "Sat Aug 15 2020 23:48:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)",
        "Address" : "874 W. Oak Place",
        "City" : "Gary",
        "State" : "Indiana",
        "Position" : {
                "Name" : "Customer Support",
                "Remote" : true,
                "FullTime" : true
        }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the supported format in the `Date` constructor.

```
new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>") returns the ISODate with the specified date.

new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss>") specifies the datetime in the client’s local timezone and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.

new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ>") specifies the datetime in UTC and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.

new Date(<integer>) specifies the datetime as milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), and returns the resulting ISODate instance.
```

The format you tried is not supported default.

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/)

And please use the below. You have a space in your key. Enclose it with quotes.

```
 {
  "Name": "Alison Davison",
  "birthday": new Date("1975-04-05"),
  "Address": "874 W. Oak Place",
  "City": "Gary",
  "State": "Indiana",
  "Position": {
    "Name": "Customer Support",
    "Remote": true,
    "Full Time": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, another quick one. Can I return the ISODate without timestamp? or the only way is to do a string?